# override and inheritance

Tags: c++, overriding, overloading

I have a Base class (Tableau) with a function (called update) and inside that function, I call another function called updateCustom.

I want to inherate my Base class with my JeuTaquin class and be able to override the updateCustom function inside JeuTaquin. So in my main when I call the function update by using a JeuTaquin object, I want to have my updateCustom from JeuTaquin starting but I don't know how to do !

Here is my update function inside Tableau:

```
template<class T>
void Tableau<T>::update()
{
int p1 = 1, p2 = 1;
int currentTurn = 1;
while(currentTurn!=tour || tour == 0){


    cout<<*this<<endl;

    updateCustom(getInput()); //HERE I CALL MY UPDATECUSTOM FUNCTION
    if(p2 == 1) 
        computerTurn();
    else
        cout<<"player 2 game end"<<endl;

    p1 = endTurn(plateau1);
    p2 = endTurn(plateau2);
    if(endCheck(p1))
        break;
    currentTurn++;
}
cout<<"game ended"<<endl;
}
```

In my class Tableau, my function updateCustom is empty (but it is declared). In my JeuTaquin class, I override my updateCustom function like this : (but it doesn't really matter to see what is inside this function )

```
template<class T>
void Tableau<T>::updateCustom(char input)
{
    int i, j;
    Case<T> *neighbours;
    while(true)
    {       
        neighbours = Tableau<T>::checkNeighbours(Tableau<T>::plateau1, i, j);
        if(input == 'z' && neighbours[0] !=nullptr)
        {
            swap(plateau1[i][j],plateau1[i-1][j]);
            cout<<"Mouvement OK"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        else if(input == 'd' && neighbours[1] !=nullptr)
        {
            swap(plateau1[i][j],plateau1[i][j+1]);
            cout<<"Mouvement OK"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        else if(input == 's' && neighbours[2] !=nullptr)
        {
            swap(plateau1[i][j],plateau1[i+1][j]);
            cout<<"Mouvement OK"<<endl;
            break;
        }
        else if(input == 'q' && neighbours[3] !=nullptr)
        {
            swap(plateau1[i][j],plateau1[i][j-1]);
            cout<<"Mouvement OK"<<endl;
            break;
        }


        cout<<"Mouvement IMPOSSIBLE"<<endl;
    }



}
```

I could not find any tips on internet, when I run my update function with an JeuTaquin object, it run my empty updateCustom from my Parent class instead of my updateCustom from my child class (JeuTaquin). Thank you for help.

Comment: Is `updateCustom` `virtual` ?

Comment: no,  updateCustom is not virtual

Comment: Well, it should be, read up about `virtual`.

Comment: ok thank you I will see

Comment: it work, I just added virtual !! THANKS

Answer (score 0):

I added virtual in my updateCustom function (only in my .h) and it works ! And when I redefine update Custom, I type

```
void JeuTaquin<T>::updateCustom(char input)
```

instead of

```
void Tableau<T>::updateCustom(char input)
```